# How to create AsyncTask on Android Java for charge Spinner from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I try load a spinner with values as get from firestore, i have two class:
1- the class what get values from firestore.
2- the class what set this values on spinner.

The step for charge is:

- Create an Instance ArrayList
- equal this to the another ArrayList get from firestore.
- Put this result on spinner

The code is this:

```
ArrayList<String> Units = new ArrayList<>();

            Products units2 = new Products();
            Units = units2.getUnits(v, CompanySelected);

            //Units.add("Unidad");
            //Units.add("Caja");
            //Units.add("Pouch");

            Spinner UnitSelector = v.findViewById(R.id.Unit);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapterUnitsSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<>(v.getRootView().getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Units);

            UnitSelector.setAdapter(adapterUnitsSpinner);
```

When i used at values what charge manually as commented on this code work fine, the spinner charge this and show item when touch, but when i get values from firestore only show this but dont select item.

I tryed test the class as get values from firestore and works. The problem is on the code was showing.

My think is what use an AsyncTask for get values and put this on ArrayList, but i dont understand how implement this.

Comment: maybe try to create the adapte and set it to the spinner only **after** you finish to retreive the data from Firebase, so paste those lines at the end of `getUnits` method

Comment: AsyncTask is a little old. A more convenient way would be to use a LiveData and a ViewModel object. If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help.